# Compile error "No global operator found" for templated overloaded operator

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I've defined a template class and overloaded operators. When compiling, I get the following error message:

> error C2677: binary '+=' : no global operator found which takes type 'Class' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Here is the relevant code of the class:

```
template<int foo>
class Class
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    template<int other_foo>
    friend class Class;

    // Constructors and copy constructors for several data type 
    // including other possibilities of "foo"; all tested.

    Class& operator+=(const Class& x)
    {
        value += x.value;
        return *this;
    }
    template<class T>
    Class& operator+=(const T& x)
    {
        this += Class(x);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

If I create two objects of, e.g., `Class<3>`; the `operator +=` works fine and does the right thing.

However, if I have an object of `Class<3>` and one of `Class<2>`, I get the above error which points at the line where "+=" is defined for T [the constructor for different value of foo works fine and is also tested].

**What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this error?** The operator is defined, just a few lines above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the necessary constructor does indeed exist and work correctly, the error in the code you've posted is

```
this += Class(x);
```

which tries to modify the value of the immutable pointer `this`. It should be

```
*this += Class(x);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are two problems, both in this line:

```
this += Class(x);
```

One: the object added to should be `*this` instead of `this`, because the latter is a pointer, not the object itself.

Two: There is no conversion constructor from `T` to `Class`. That is, you cannot convert from `Class<3>` to `Class<2>` so the `Class(x)` will not compile. The solution would be to add it:

```
template<int other> Class(const Class<other> &o)
{}
```

Comment: Thanks! It now works. Thanks for the comment with the constructor from T to Class; this was already done but not included in my code snippet to not have a long code above.